# xamarin how to play youtube video in youtube app from my ios app by a button

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am developing a ios app with xamarin, in c#. I have a "video" `UIViewController`, button icon.

I need to play a youtube video from my app, that points to a youtube app installed on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("vnd.youtube://video_id"));
```

For `video_id` check the video url.